# What is the right preposition when you write about limiting choices

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

Is this the right way to write about choices limitation.

> Students' choices should be restricted\limited **to\in** vocational
>   courses.

Or

> Your choices are limited **to\in** the following options (a or b or c)

Comment: do you have any thoughts about what might be right and why?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. If there are three choices, can you show three complete sentences?

Comment: My question is about using the correct preposition "to or in" when you write about choices limitation or selecting from finite options. I will change the title.

Answer (score 1):

Both **to** and **in** are correct, but the meaning is radically different.

to -> the only possible choices are presented next

in -> the choices in (what is next) are limited

---

restricted **to** vocational courses = only vocational courses are allowed

restricted **in** vocational courses = when speaking about vocational courses, choices should be limited

---

limited **to** the following options (a or b or c) = only options a or b or c are possible

limited **in** the following options = (it does not actually make sense)

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> Students' choices should be restricted\limited **to** vocational courses.

and

> Your choices are limited **to** a or b or c